# Gun flies off when moving the camera (BGE)

Tags: game-engine

I'm making a fps shooter and I can't seem to get the vertical camera movement working correctly. When moving the camera, my gun flies off in a weird direction. How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance

[link to the .blend](https://doc-0c-34-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/5v28dlie1oqhqtfd6u98md0l29vsrp8i/j5odqjfjkdem772mmknhcghqgdo8hln6/1488031200000/05622286536901932456/05622286536901932456/0BzltoZKmXtq8NkxSWk0wXzZ0eGc?e=download)

Comment: The access to your link is denied. You can also upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Is the gun a child of the camera?

Comment: yes it is ,i tried making it a child of the body but then the body moves vertically